# Use matlab connunicate to bittrex api error (APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED)

Tags: matlab, api

I have the following code and I also read the post from Bittrex. My nonce and apikey are used for HMAC calculation, but I receive the APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED error.

> For this version, we use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append apikey
>   and nonce to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it
>   under an apisign header. Note: the nonce is not respected right now
>   but will be enforced later.

```
if true
  % code
url_base = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders';
body = [url_base,'?apikey=',apikey,'&nonce=',nonce];
sign = hmac(secret_key, body, 'SHA-512');
json = urlread( body, 'Get', {'apisign', sign} )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `urlread` is not recommended anymore (reference [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html)), just for the sake of curiosity, try the currently recommended alternative `webread`:

```
url_base = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders/';
url_full = [url_base '?apikey=' apikey '&nonce=' nonce];
sign = hmac(secret_key,url_full,'SHA-512');

opt = weboptions('ContentType','json','HeaderFields',{'apisign' sign},'RequestMethod','get');
json = webread(url_full,opt);
```

Also, don't forget to put a breakpoint in your code and check how `sign` looks like, just to be sure you are forwarding properly formatted data in your HTTPS request headers.